# Moodle rest post returning error with feature core_user_get_users_by_field

Tags: web-services, rest, post, moodle

Hi I'm new with moodle and I'm getting an error when calling the webservice.

Currently I'm trying to retrieve a user from moodle with the following function core_user_get_users_by_field and I'm using rest service to do so. I already managed to create a user thus I am authenticated to use the service.

the error that I'm receiving is

> Missing required key in single structure: field

The bellow is the code was used to create a User. the issue that I got from the error is that the parameter that I need to send for the post is not formatted well. Does anyone know how to search correctly with this method or any other method.

```
        String token = "token";

        String postData = "username=username";

        string createRequest = string.Format("http://domain/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken={0}&wsfunction={1}&moodlewsrestformat=json", token, "core_user_get_users_by_field");

        // Call Moodle REST Service
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(createRequest);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Encode the parameters as form data:
        byte[] formData =
            UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        req.ContentLength = formData.Length;

        // Write out the form Data to the request:
        using (Stream post = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            post.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
        }


        // Get the Response
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Stream resStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
        string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Deserialize
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        if (contents.Contains("exception"))
        {
            // Error
            MoodleException moodleError = serializer.Deserialize<MoodleException>(contents);
        }
        else
        {
            // Good

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webservice `core_user_get_users_by_field` needs an associative array given as parameter with the following key:values
'field': 'id'
'values': array of integers (must be an array, possibly with just one value)

In PHP it would be, for example:

```
$parameters = array('field' => 'id', 'values' => array(13));
```

It means: the user whose 'id' has the value of 13. Of course, you can use other parameters as well:   ('field'=>'lastname', 'values'=> array('Smith'))
The parameters you can choose are the fields of the Moodle 'user' table.
Try to build these parameters in your `postData` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's URL that work with my put this url in postman and set http method to post method

```
hostname/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=any_token&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&field=email&values[0]=h@fci.com
&moodlewsrestformat=json
```

Comment: Does it work for you? I've tried to make it and don't any response